# np.linalg.norm does not work for CSR matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a 220,000 x 34 matrix represented as a Numpy CSR matrix.  When I try to take the row-wise norm of the matrix, I get an exception:

```
>>> np.linalg.norm(csr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packa
ges\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 2450, in norm
    sqnorm = dot(x, x)
  File "C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packa
ges\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 480, in __mul__
    raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
ValueError: dimension mismatch
>>> csr
<3x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
        with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Is there a restriction on which Numpy methods/functions work with CSR matrixes?

In desperation, I tried to code around this by doing an element-wise multiplication of the matrix with itself and then summing along the rows, but I got an exception with that, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy` functions not working on `sparse` matrices is the rule, not the exception.

Here is a workaround operating directly on the `csr` representation:

```
from scipy.sparse import random

A = random(1000,500,format="csr")

def sparse_row_norm(A):
    out = np.zeros(A.shape[0])
    # ufunc.reduceat only works properly for strictly increasing points
    # as a workaround we filter out empty rows
    nz, = np.diff(A.indptr).nonzero()
    out[nz] = np.sqrt(np.add.reduceat(np.square(A.data),A.indptr[nz]))
    return out

# compare to brute force (convert to dense array) method
np.allclose(sparse_row_norm(A),np.linalg.norm(A.A,axis=1))
# True

# results are the same but speed is much better
timeit(lambda:sparse_row_norm(A),number=1000)
# 0.04653145093470812
timeit(lambda:np.linalg.norm(A.A,axis=1),number=1000)
# 1.6365239119622856
```

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
np.linalg.norm(csr.toarray())
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
csr = csr_matrix((3, 4), dtype=np.int8).toarray()
np.linalg.norm(csr)
0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function `snorm` that works on both;
`snorm( sparsematrix, axis=1 )` gets you row norms --

```
import numpy as np    
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse import linalg as sslin

def snorm( A, ord=None, axis=None ):
    """ norm of either scipy sparse matrix or numpy dense ndarray
        ord=None: sqrt( sum Aij^2 ), Frobenius norm
        ord=np.inf: max |Aij|
        axis=None: all,  axis=0: columns,  axis=1: rows
    """
    if sparse.issparse( A ):
        return sslin.norm( A, ord=ord, axis=axis )
        # https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.norm.html
    else:
        return np.linalg.norm( A, ord=ord, axis=axis )


#...............................................................................
# test snorm --
for A in [np.array([[ 1, 2 ], [3, 4] ]),
        np.eye( 0 )]:
    print( "\nA: \n", A )
    S = sparse.csr_matrix( A )
    for axis in [None, 0, 1]:
        npnorm = snorm( A, axis=axis )
        sparsenorm = snorm( S, axis=axis )
        print( "snorm axis %s: %s  %s " % (axis, npnorm, sparsenorm ))
```